# MacBook Air M2 - Clamshell mode does not work when using display port

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

Hoping to find a solution here.

So my current setup is

- Monitor: Dell 34 Inch Model Number S3422DWG
- Docking Station: HP USB-C Dock G5, model number: 26D32AA

My issue is if I use the display port cable to connect the monitor, the clamshell mode does not work, the screen will just remain blank, detecting for signal. But if I use HDMI cable, everything works perfectly.

Just wondering if anyone has encountered this issue with their MacBook Air M2? I have tried a new Display Port cable and still could not get the clamshell mode to work.

Note: for my Windows laptop, I can get both DisplayPort and HDMI to work in clamshell mode.

Comment: I would also check on the HP support boards in case this is a known issue and/or there is a known fix.